# Remove Whitespace from strings while Splitting by ","

Tags: java, regex

I need to identify the words after some keyword and before the symbols `"="` OR `";"`

I am using the below approach by splitting

```
    String res = "private String   name1, name2,  name3; ";
    Matcher matcherWithCommar = Pattern
            .compile("(?<=^private)\\W+(String|float|long|short|double|byte|boolean|int|char)\\W+(.+?)(;|=)",
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(res);

    if (matcherWithCommar.find()) {
        System.out.println("Varibels : " + matcherWithCommar.group(2).trim());
        String[] parameters = matcherWithCommar.group(2).trim().split(Pattern.quote(","));
        for (int r = 0; r < parameters.length; r++) {
            System.out.println("names: " + parameters[r]);

        }
    }
```

this solution brings the output  with white spaces

and my Output was like

```
Varibels : name1, name2,  name3
names: name1
names:  name2
names:   name3
```

but i need it like this

```
Varibels : name1, name2,  name3
names: name1
names: name2
names: name3
```

without white spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.split(Pattern.quote(","));` to a regex pattern matching white space before and after the comma (which you don't need to quote). Like,

```
.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

with just that change I get

```
Varibels : name1, name2,  name3
names: name1
names: name2
names: name3
```